# Adding New Custom Insert Options

Tags: powershell-extensions, xm-cloud

Is there anyways that I can create a custom insert options like this for JSS Site (Properties Sites)? We want to integrate some Powershell script along the creation process such as display the form with couple fields and values and we can pull relevant data based on the information provided in that form (those fields can be optional). [image]Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is an Integration Point for SPE to add custom scripts to the Insert Options menu.

You can read more about it in [the official docs here](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/integration-points/content-editor#insert-item).